# After clicking Fb share button the pop up does't appear. What appead is fb_dialog_box

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress

please see the demo problem at [Here](http://video.69download.com) i have created my own plugin that can make the video be seen when user share the video. I have made three files , one is hook, the next one is class and other one is for update. My plugins 99% function works here. see

```
<?php

class VideoLock {
    
    protected static $running = false;

    const PLUGIN_PREFIX = "VL";

    const SLUG = 'videolock';

    protected $sharesTableName;

    protected $viewsTableName;

    protected $_key;

    public function __construct() {
        //create the correctly prefixed table name
        global $wpdb;
        $this->sharesTableName = $wpdb->prefix."videolock_shares";
        $this->viewsTableName = $wpdb->prefix."videolock_views";

    }
    
    public function tinymceShortcodePlugin($plugin_array) {
       $plugin_array['videolock'] = $this->file('/assets/js/shortcodeplugin.js');
       return $plugin_array;
    }

    public function tinymceShortcodeButton($buttons) {
       array_push($buttons, "separator", "videolock");
       return $buttons;
    }

    public function init() {

        if ( ( current_user_can('edit_posts') || current_user_can('edit_pages') ) && 
            get_user_option('rich_editing') ) {
            //register admin editor shortcode creator
            add_filter("mce_external_plugins",  $this->callback('tinymceShortcodePlugin'));
            add_filter('mce_buttons',           $this->callback('tinymceShortcodeButton'));
        }
        
        //register admin tinymce shortcode insert plugin
        wp_enqueue_style($this->prefix('locker-style'), $this->file('/assets/css/blocker.css'));
        wp_enqueue_script($this->prefix('locker-script'), $this->file('/assets/js/blocker.js?v=2'), 
                          array('jquery','swfobject'));

        //enqueue swfobject if not present
        if( wp_script_is('swfobject') ) {
            wp_enqueue_script('swfobject', $this->file('/assets/js/swfobject.js'));
        }

        //register plugin options
        add_option('facebook-id');
        add_option('share-message', 'Unlock this video by sharing it on facebook !');
        add_option('video-size', '560x315');

        new VideoLockUpdate( $this->getKey() );
    }

    public static function getVersion() {

        $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/version';
        if( file_exists($file)) {
            return trim(file_get_contents($file));
        }

        return '0';
    }

    public function getKey() {

        if( $this->_key ) {
            return $this->_key;
        }

        $file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/licence.php';
        
        if( file_exists($file)) {
            include $file;
            $this->_key = defined('VIDEOLOCK_LICENCE_KEY') ? VIDEOLOCK_LICENCE_KEY : null;
            return $this->_key;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function install() {

        global $wpdb;

        $key = $this->getKey();

        if( !$key ) {
            wp_die('Fail to activate this plugin. You need a valid licence key for activation. For more informations contact us at <a href="mailto:support@wpvideolock.com">support@wpvideolock.com</a> or the <a href="http://www.wpvideolock.com/contact-us/">online form</a><br/>If you bought this plugin, please send your email address used for buying the plugin to resend a functional version.<br/>Thank you!');
        }

        $request = wp_remote_post('http://update.wpvideolock.com/', array('body' => array('action' => 'validate-key', 'key'=>$key)));
        if (!is_wp_error($request) || wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($request) === 200) {
            $response = trim($request['body']);
            if( $response != 'ok' ) {
                wp_die($response);
            }
        }

        update_option('facebook-id', '');
        update_option('share-message', 'Share on facebook to unlock this video .');
        update_option('video-size', '560x315');

        if(!in_array($this->sharesTableName,$wpdb->tables())) {
            
            $sql = "CREATE TABLE `" . $this->sharesTableName . "` (
                        id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                        url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                        ip VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
                        post INT(11) NOT NULL,
                        time DATETIME,
                        `share_id` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
                        `gender` ENUM(  'female',  'male' ),
                       PRIMARY KEY ( id )
                    )";

            $wpdb->query($sql);
        }

        if(!in_array($this->viewsTableName,$wpdb->tables())) {

            $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `" . $this->viewsTableName . "` (
                      `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                      `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
                      `date` date NOT NULL,
                      UNIQUE KEY `post_id` (`post_id`,`date`)
                    )";

            $wpdb->query($sql);
        }
    }

    public function uninstall() {

        global $wpdb;
        
        $backup = false; // Take it from options after user change settings for the plugin to create backup

        if( $backup ) {

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $this->sharesTableName . "`";
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
            if( count($results) ) {
                $uploads_dir = wp_upload_dir();
                $backup_file = $uploads_dir['basedir'].'/videolock_backup.txt';
                file_put_contents($backup_file,serialize($results));
            }
        }

        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE `" . $this->sharesTableName . "`");
        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE `" . $this->viewsTableName . "`");

        delete_option('facebook-id', '');
        delete_option('share-message', 'Share on facebook to unlock this video .');
        delete_option('video-size', '560x315');
    }

    public function getYoutubeId( $url ) {

        $url = strip_tags($url);
        $url = parse_url($url);
        $query = $url['query'];
        //If video is in a format like this
        // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKmuUDQdcXc
        if($query) {
            $id = str_replace("v=","",$query);
            return $id;
        }
        //if video is in a format like this
        // http://youtu.be/fKmuUDQdcXc
        else {
            $path = $url['path'];
            $id = str_replace("/","",$path);
            return $id;
        }
    }

    public function shortcode( $atts ) {
        
        global $wpdb;
 
        //extract attributes to function scope
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'url' => false,
            'id' => false,
            'width' => '420',
            'height' => '315',
            'expire' => 0,
            'message' => get_option('share-message'),
        ), $atts ) );

        //do not show anything if to id or url
        if( $url === false && $id === false ) {
            return null;
        }

        //extract the video id in case url is passed
        if( $url ) {
            $id = $this->getYoutubeId($url);
        }

        $image = 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $id . '/0.jpg';
    
        $view = new View( dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/blocker.php' );

        $view->image = $image;
        $view->id = $id;
        $view->url = $url;
        $view->width = $width;
        $view->height = $height;
        $view->message = $message;
        $view->expire = $expire;
        
        //if there werent any views today insert it
        //else increment it
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $this->viewsTableName . "`
            (`post_id`,`views`,`date`)
                VALUES
            ('" . get_the_ID() . "',1,CURDATE())
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=views+1;";

        $wpdb->query($sql);

        $view->helper('isLocked', $this->callback('isLocked'));

        return $view->render();
    }

    public function actionLinks( $links, $file ) {
        
        $url = admin_url( 'admin.php?page=videolock/dashboard.php' );
        if ( $file == plugin_basename( dirname(__FILE__).'/videolock.php' ) ) {
            $links[] = '<a href="' . $url . '">'.__( 'Dashboard' ).'</a>';
        }

        return $links;
    }

    public function isLocked( $postid = null ) {

        global $wpdb;

        $postid = is_numeric($postid) ? $postid : get_the_ID();

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM `" . $this->sharesTableName . "` WHERE `post`=%d AND `ip`=%s AND `url`=%s LIMIT 1";

        $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $postid, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $url);
        
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        if( isset($result[0]) ) {
            return $result[0]->total == '0';
        }

        return true;
    }

    public function share() {

        global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

        $url= $wpdb->escape($_POST['link']);
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $postId = intval($_POST['post']);
        $share = $_POST['share'];
        $gender = null;

        $share_parts=explode('_', $share);
        
        if(count($share_parts)) {
            $share_user = $share_parts[0];
            if($share_user) {
                try {
                    $user_data = json_decode(@file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/' . $share_user));
                $gender = isset($user_data->gender) ? $user_data->gender : null;
                }catch(Exception $e) {}
            }
        }

        $result = $wpdb->insert($this->sharesTableName,array(
            'url'       => $url,
            'ip'        => $ip,
            'post'      => $postId,
            'time'      => current_time('mysql', 1),
            'share_id'  => $share,
            'gender'    => $gender
        ));

        echo $result ? '1':'0';

        die();
    }

    public function shareLogged() {
        //not implemented yet for logged users
        $this->share();
    }

    public function queueAdminScripts() {
        wp_localize_script( $this->prefix('blocker-jsobj'), 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => 1234 ) );


        wp_enqueue_script($this->prefix('dashboard-script'), $this->file('/assets/js/dashboard.js'), array('jquery', $this->prefix('flot')));
        wp_enqueue_script($this->prefix('flot'), $this->file('/assets/js/flot/jquery.flot.js'));
        wp_enqueue_script($this->prefix('flot.time'), $this->file('/assets/js/flot/jquery.flot.time.js'));
    }

    public function createDashboard() {
        global $wpdb;

        $sql = "SELECT SUM(views) as views, post_id FROM `" . $this->viewsTableName . "` GROUP BY post_id";
        $postsViews = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        wp_enqueue_style($this->prefix('fresh'), '/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.min.css?ver=3.7.1');
        wp_enqueue_style($this->prefix('dashboard-theme'), $this->file('/assets/css/dashboard.css'));

        include dirname(__FILE__) . '/views/dashboard.php';
    }

    public function createAdminMenu() {

        $menu_icon = $this->file('/assets/images/logo.png');
        $content_callback = $this->callback('createDashboard');
        //add admin left pannel menu
        add_menu_page( __('Video Lock'), 
                   __('Video Lock'),
                   __('manage_options'),
                   'videolock/dashboard.php', $content_callback , $menu_icon );
    }

    private function _getShares($post,$date) {

        global $wpdb;

        //get timestamp from date
        $timestamp = strtotime($date);

        //calculate start and end of the day
        $startTime =  date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',$timestamp);
        $endTime = date('Y-m-d 23:59:59',$timestamp);

        //select the shares for the day of the timestamp
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as shares FROM `" . $this->sharesTableName . "`
                WHERE `post` = %d AND `time` BETWEEN '$startTime' AND '$endTime'";
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $post);
        $result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        if( isset($result[0]) ) {
            return $result[0]->shares;
        }
        else return 0;

    }
    public function shareStats() {

        global $wpdb;

        $response = array();
        $postId = $_POST['post'];

        //get views per day
        $sql = "SELECT views,`date` AS `date` FROM `" . $this->viewsTableName . "` WHERE `post_id`=%d";
        $sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $postId);
        $dates = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $hasToday = false;

        //generate response
        foreach($dates as $date) {

            //check if today exists (if not we can add it later)
            if($date->date == $today) {
                $hasToday = true;
            }

            $jsDate = strtotime($date->date)*1000;
            $response['views'][]  = array($jsDate ,$date->views);
            $response['shares'][] = array($jsDate , $this->_getShares( $postId, $date->date ));
        }

        //if we don't have today,
        //add it as 0 to the graph
        if(!$hasToday) {
            $today = strtotime($today) * 1000;
            $response['views'][]  = array( $today , 0 );
            $response['shares'][] = array( $today , 0 );
        }

        echo json_encode($response);
        exit();
    }

    public function saveSettings() {

        $settings = $_POST['data'];

        update_option('facebook-id', $settings[0]['value']);
        update_option('share-message', $settings[1]['value']);
        update_option('video-size', $settings[2]['value']);
        if($settings[2]['value'] == 'custom') {
            update_option('video-width', $settings[3]['value']);
            update_option('video-height', $settings[4]['value']);
        }
        else {
            delete_option('video-height');
            delete_option('video-width');
        }
    }

    private function _noFacebookId(){

        $facebookId = get_option('facebook-id');

        if(empty($facebookId) || !$facebookId )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    function adminNotice() {
        echo '<div class="updated">
                <p>You have successfully installed WordPress Video Lock Plugin.
                Please take a minute to <a href="admin.php?page=videolock/dashboard.php#fbid">add your facebook API key</a> and get started</p>
            </div>
        ';

    }


    private function file( $name ) {

        if( strpos($name, '/') !== 0 ) {
            $name = '/' . $name;
        }

        return plugins_url() . '/videolock' . $name;
    }

    private function prefix( $string ) {
        return VideoLock::PLUGIN_PREFIX . $string;
    }

    private function callback($method) {
        return array($this, $method);
    }

    public function run() {

        if( self::$running ) {
            throw new Exception("The Youtube Locker already running!");
        }

        //get the plugin script name for install/uninstall hooks
        $pluginFile = dirname(__FILE__) . '/videolock.php';

        //installation / dezinstalation hooks
        register_activation_hook( $pluginFile,  $this->callback('install') );
        register_deactivation_hook( $pluginFile,$this->callback('uninstall') );

        //short codes
        add_shortcode( 'youtubelocker',         $this->callback('shortcode') );
        add_shortcode( 'videolock',             $this->callback('shortcode') );
        
        //filters
        add_filter('plugin_action_links',       $this->callback('actionLinks'), 10, 2 );
        
        //add ajax callback
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_video_share',$this->callback('share') );
        add_action('wp_ajax_video_share',       $this->callback('shareLogged') );
        add_action('wp_ajax_videolock_save_settings', $this->callback('saveSettings') );
        add_action('wp_ajax_videolock_share_stats', $this->callback('shareStats'));
        add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts',     $this->callback('queueAdminScripts') );
        add_action('admin_menu',                $this->callback('createAdminMenu') );

        if($this->_noFacebookId()) {
            add_action('admin_notices',             $this->callback('adminNotice') );
        }

        add_action('init',                      $this->callback('init'), 0);




        self::$running = true;
    }

}
```

But somehow it's not working as expected. When user first share the video it works like charm but it makes error when the same user share another. it doesnt open the sharer.php it opens a fb dialog box and load for infinity time. I hope you guys can help me to solve that. FYI after the completation of the plugin the plugin will be freeware in wp.org